# How to create a 301 redirect in .htaccess for *.olddomain.com to *.newdomain.com

Tags: .htaccess

I've checked many ways for redirecting old domain to new domain. But I did not find any way for that.

All my subfolder of my site is using subdomain address, such as myfolder.domain.com, so it built many many subdomains. Now I want to redirect all of them to new domain.

redirect *.olddomain.com to *.newdomain.com. Can anybody who know .htaccess can help me with this? I'd really really appreciate it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> redirect *.olddomain.com to *.newdomain.com. Can anybody who know .htaccess can help me with this?

As long as all of your `*.olddomain.com` domains all point to the same document root, you can just put these rules in the htaccess file in that directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect the browser from:

`http://foo.olddomain.com/bar.html` to 
**`http://foo.newdomain.com/bar.html`**